# Specifying multiple cd commands in a .command file

Tags: macos, command-line

I have a very small `.command` file set up on a mac server that's basically just meant to launch a Python process. It's more intuitive for other people to use than opening terminal, typing out 'python' then dragging the file on.

However this also requires that I change directory first, since the script will operate on files on the server and needs to operate from the same directory it's contained in. The problem is that the two people that need to use this have different paths to the file, because of the way the server is set up.

Since I can't change the servers to have the same paths, I instead tried out having `cd` commands for *both* paths, and that does seem to work. Since one path will always not exist and the other will one command fails while the other runs.

```
cd /Volumes/Server/scripts/Script
cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD2/Server/Scripts/Script
python Process.py
```

Which will give me this response:

```
/Volumes/Server/scripts/Script ; exit;
/Volumes/Macintosh\ HD2/Server/Scripts/Script: line 2: cd: /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD2/Server/Scripts/Script: No such file or directory
### My script runs here with the correct path ###
```

This seems to work, but I know that if for some reason one person had both paths as valid paths, I'd run into trouble. I also don't know if this could lead to other issues. Even if it looks like the errors pass silently, I can't be sure they'll never cause problems. So I have two parts to the question, what are the disadvantages to using the commands this way and is there a better way I should set this `.command` file up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a little bit of logic to determine if certain directories exist before attempting to enter them:

```
if [ -d "$DIRECTORY" ]; then
    # Control will enter here if $DIRECTORY exists.
fi
```

(see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-shell-script)

This way you can control the behavior when one, both, or neither directories exist.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Led me down a rabbit hole of learning shell scripting and I got a lot of information to help me.